# Chamar dados do banco com $http get

Tags: php, angularjs

Não estou conseguindo chamar os dados do banco com o método abaixo:

```
<div class="container" ng-app="appCat">
    <div class="row" ng-controller="appCatCtrl">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <tr>
                <th>Nome</th>
                <th>Telefone</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="x in category">
                <td>{{x.cat}}</td>
                <td>{{x.sub}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

No arquivo JS:

```
angular.module("appCat", []);
angular.module("appCat").controller("appCatCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.category = [];
    var showCat() {
        $http.get("proc_cat.php").then(function(response) {
            $scope.category = response.data;
        });
    }
    showCat();
});
```

e no PHP:

```
try {
    $con = new PDO($dns, $user, $pass);
    if(!$con){
        echo "Não foi possivel conectar com Banco de Dados!";
    }
    $query = $con->prepare('SELECT * FROM category');
        $query->execute();
        $out = "[";
        while($result = $query->fetch()){
            if ($out != "[") {
                $out .= ",";
            }
            $out .= '{"cat": "'.$result["name_cat"].'",';
            $out .= '"sub": "'.$result["sub_cat"].'"}';
        }
        $out .= "]";
        echo utf8_encode($out);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Erro: ". $e->getMessage();
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiramente a sua definição de variável está incorreta, tente da seguinte maneira:

```
var showCat = function() {...
```

Outra coisa seria o seu tratamento de dados no lado do PHP. Você está fazendo algo muito complexo para gerar a array, sendo que poderia apenas usar as funções `json_encode()` (para enviar do PHP para o Angular - JS) e `json_decode()` (para enviar do Angular - JS para o PHP).

```
$query->execute();
$resposta = $query->fetchAll();
return json_encode($resposta);
```

Assim você também já envia os dados em `JSON`.

Answer (score 1):

A forma que você está usando a função `json_encode` está estranha.

Você não precisa criar uma *string* formatada em *json*, pode passar diretamente o *array* de resultados para ele:

(Estou assumindo que esse arquivo PHP é só um trecho do código, se for o arquivo inteiro ele sempre vai retornar "Não foi possivel conectar com Banco de Dados!")

```
try {
    $con = new PDO($dns, $user, $pass);
    if(!$con){
        echo "Não foi possivel conectar com Banco de Dados!";
    }
    $query = $con->prepare('SELECT * FROM category');
        $query->execute();

        $out = [];

        while($result = $query->fetch()){
            $out[] = [
                'cat' => $result["name_cat"],
                'sub' => $result["sub_cat"],
            ];
        }

        echo utf8_encode($out);

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Erro: ". $e->getMessage();
};
```